# Update Windows 7 Embedded

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates, windows-embedded-7

I have Windows 7 Embedded x64. Recently I tried to do the updates, but saw that nothing happens when i click on the button check for updates. What may be the problem? 3 months ago I did the updates but thy could not be saved (computer needed to restart) and I lost them. Probably they were stored in the RAM or something like that... Can you provide me any help in first place why i can not even look for updates, than how to store them after restart?

[image]

Comment: When you launch `Windows Update` and check for updates are updates even found?

Comment: No, I can not even look for updates. I can not provide printscreen in the moment but i googled what i have on my screen when i try to update.
[link](http://www.systemcontrol.com.au/images/captures/Update-error-on-Windows-7.JPG)
When i click the button, notghing happens.

Comment: When does your system indicate the last update happened?

Comment: The middle of November last year.

Comment: See if [this link helps](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/troubleshoot-problems-installing-updates#1TC=windows-7)